# why can't my openfile connect to the convert and save functions?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I tried my best to get this working.
Main problem: the user chooses his xml data and this should be handed over
to the xml_to_json converter and save the file.
But the chosen file cant connect with the convert and save button.
I hope you can help me out with this one.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json
import xmltodict
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

# General setup
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Convert XML to JSON")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.configure(bg="#333333")


# Open File
def openfile():
    #read xml
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a File" , filetypes=[("xml files", "*.xml")])
    f_xml = open(path, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    f_read = f_xml.read()
    

    # convert xml to json
    parsed_data = xmltodict.parse(f_read, process_namespaces=False)
    json_conv = json.dumps(parsed_data, indent=4)
    
    return json_conv
    
# save file
def savefile(openfile):
        file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes=[("json files", "*.json")])
        f_json = open(file, "w", encoding='utf-8')
        f_json.write(openfile)

# Frame
frame = tk.Frame(bg="#333333")

# label and Entery

title_label = tk.Label(frame, text="XML TO JSON Converter", bg="#3FFFFF", fg="#FF3389", font=("Arial", 30))
xml_label = tk.Label(frame, text="XML file input", bg="#3FFFFF", fg="#FF3399", font=("Arial", 15))
button_xml_label = tk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=lambda:openfile(), font=("Arial", 15))
JSON_label = tk.Label(frame, text="JSON file output", bg="#3FFFFF", fg="#FF3399", font=("Arial", 15))
button_save_label = tk.Button(frame, text="Convert & Save", command=lambda:savefile(), font=("Arial", 15))


# Placing widgets on the screen
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="news", pady=40)
xml_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
button_xml_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, padx= 10, pady=20)
JSON_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_save_label.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=5, pady=20)


frame.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `openfile` just returns the data, but a tkinter command callback isn't expected to return anything.  If you want the data shoved in a control, then you have to put it there.  And your `savefile` doesn't do anything -- `savefile` isn't going to be passed anything.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. As you said, I just needed to shove the lines in savefile to the end of openfile and getting rid of "return json_conv". It's working now :)